# App_GlobalResources from resx file in my class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, app-globalresources

How to transfer in runtime my cystom resrouce file in my class library to App_GlobalResources folder in my mvc web application?

Comment: Why you need this ? May be you doing something in wrong way ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032592/resources-at-class-library-project

Comment: Hi..   Alexey Semidotsky, i need to do, because my resources are shared by 5 mvc apps and to manage the resources would be better to manager in a class library

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? because my application exactly need this feature too.