# Tesseract OCR in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to implement Tesseract OCR in my project.
I've got two projects in my solution:

- Portal - which is ASP.NET MVC App
- OCR - which is a class library, where I have Tesseract

In OCR class library, I have method:

```
using (var ocrEngine = new TesseractEngine(/*WHAT DOES COME HERE?*/, "eng", EngineMode.Default))
            {

                using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(new Bitmap(imageFilePath)))
                {
                    using (var page = ocrEngine.Process(pix))
                    {
                        output = page.GetText();
                    }
                }
            }
```

In my project I have folder **tessdata**, but I don't know how to reference it, to make everything work. I tried:

```
@"./tessdata"
```

or

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/tessdata")
```

but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Server.MapPath` and the demo works fine.

```
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Server.MapPath(@"~/tessdata"), "eng", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
        using (var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.InputStream))
        {
            using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
            {

                using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can view the full source code [here](https://github.com/quannt/tesseract-aspnet)

Comment: This works perfectly for asp.net mvc projects, but as I've written before, I have two projects in solution, and the one in which I am trying to make tesseract work is Class Library, not ASP.NET MVC project. I can't use Server.MapPath()

Comment: @Siemko I see, this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032592/resources-at-class-library-project#

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach:

```
Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"tessdata")
```

like below :

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"tessdata"), "eng", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
        using (var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.InputStream))
        {
            using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
            {

                using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath return directory od Portal(the startup project), what I want to achieve, is to get directory of OCR project.
eg.
not "C:\Projects\mypro\Portal\", but
"C:\Projects\mypro\OCR\

Comment: Why you are not using static path

Answer (score 0):

What I did, was just moving the tessdata folder to the main ASP.NET MVC project, and then used simple `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"tessdata")` as @Sunil Kumar suggested.