# Building .Net library so that resources are kept separate (Winforms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

When we build our software, a single character change in the codebase will cause the entire project DLL to be regenerated.

Within the DLLs, roughly 80% of the total DLL size is the content of the .resx files from our forms (as evidenced by dumping the content using ILDASM). As these files change far less frequently, I wanted to know if there's a way to keep the resources in a separated Codebase.Resources.dll with the goal of having the builds generate fewer new files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3033027/4846648 discusses that.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want. That is "I have an external resource and I want to include it as is it's part of my project". I'm looking for "I have a part of the project and, when I build, I want it kept as an external resource"